# Codeigniter: Specify user data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm trying to get specific user data to show up on the profile.

It shows data, but not the correct info for that profile.

Model:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function show_users()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $query_result = $query->result();
    return $query_result;
}

public function showUserID($data)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('id ', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
 }
```

Controller:

```
 public function user()
    {

        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['users'] = $this->user_model->show_users();   
        $data['single_user'] = $this->user_model->showUserID($id);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');              
        $this->load->view('pages/profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
```

View:

```
   <?php $username = $_SESSION['username'];?>
   <?php echo $username;?> 's Profile

 <?php foreach ($users as $user): 
    if ($user == $username) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/Profile/user/" . $user->id; ?>">
    <?php echo $user->username; }?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; >

<h4>User ID:</h4> <h5> <?php echo $user->id; ?></h5>
<h4>Age:</h4> <h5><?php echo $user->age; ?></h5>
```

I'm just not sure how to specify it for the current logged in user.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you want to show data of a "single_user"? but in your view you query all users...

Comment: When I change it to foreach($single_user as $singleuser), it gives me '$singleuser undefined variable'.

Comment: and where does `$_SESSION['username']` come from? does it have the correct value?

Comment: From my login controller. It shows the current username logged in, and it is correct. Just not sure how to get the data to display for the specific user.

Comment: I don't recommend you to use `$_SESSION['username']`, you should use ci's session library

Comment: Are you getting value for  ` $id` in controller `user`. check that with `echo $id; exit;` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view

```
<?php $username = $_SESSION['username'];?>
  <?php echo $username;?> 's Profile

<?php foreach ($users as $user): 
if ($user->username == $username) { ?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/Profile/user/" . $user->id; ?>">
<?php echo $user->username; }?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; >

 <h4>User ID:</h4> <h5> <?php echo $user->id; ?></h5>
 <h4>Age:</h4> <h5><?php echo $user->age; ?></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `$id` in your controller.

Change your **model** to

```
public function showUserID($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id ', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result_array();

 }
```

Change your **view** to(no neeed of foreach loop)

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/Profile/user/" . $single_user[0]['id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $single_user[0]['id']; }?></a></li>
     <?php endforeach; >

     <h4>User ID:</h4> <h5> <?php echo $single_user[0]['id']; ?></h5>
     <h4>Age:</h4> <h5><?php echo $single_user[0]['age']; ?></h5>
```